# iOS, How To Reset All App Permissions for Testing Purposes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, permissions, ios-permissions

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to reset all of the app permissions in the app I am working on. I am switching around the location of the permission in my app, and I would like to test it. However, I can't figure out how to reset these permissions so they will prompt me again. Not sure if these matter but the permissions are Camera, Location, iCloud, PhotoLibrary, and Contact Book.

I have tried deleting the app and changing the permissions in settings, but neither worked.

If this is an in-code answer, I am using swift, Thanks!

Comment: If you are on a simulator, you can simply reset all content and settings, and they should pop up again.
Simulator > Simulator > Reset content and settings

Comment: `Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy` will reset permissions for *ALL* installed applications.

Comment: `Reset Location & Privacy` doesn't work for me. The notification permission dialog only pops up on first launch of the app.